# How to move Bootstrap pagination in-line with buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

[image]

See the image above - I have Bootstrap dropdowns on the left, and buttons on the right. They're nicely aligned, but I'd like to move the pagination up so it's in between them to make better use of the space. Now currently the pagination code is further down, but if I move it between the dropdowns and buttons, it causes what you see in the second image. How can I have everything aligned?

[image]

Bootiply here: http://www.bootply.com/5Ufnpj317Z

EDIT: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

please find attached images and do changes as per red area.

Comment: This has really helped - last thing is I need the left dropdowns (Location and Type) to align with the table below, and to not have such a big gap between them: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5cn2T.png

Comment: I've figured out if I put both left dropdowns in one div with col-md-2, they sit together nicely. But how can I get them to left-align with the table below?

Answer (score 1):

I've rearranged a fair bit of your code, summarised as follows:

- introduced bootstrap container and rows
- removed panel-body class
- removed pull-right class from the buttons on the right
- added test.css for some custom adjustments
- fixed indenting

It looks ok an a wide screen, but elements will stack on top of each other on smaller screens.
[image: Screenshot of page with all elements in one row]

```css
/*test.css*/
#dropdownMenu1-div{
    display:inline;
}

#dropdownMenu2-div{
    display:inline;
}

.pagination{
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>

    <h2 class="text-center">Browse</h2>
    <hr class="no-bottom-pad">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <div class="dropdown inline-control" id="dropdownMenu1-div"">
                        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Location:
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                            <li><a href="browse.php?">all</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;loc=3">London Waterloo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;loc=2">London Waterloo 3F workshop</a></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;loc=1">London Waterloo comms room</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown inline-control" id="dropdownMenu2-div">
                      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Type:
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                      </button>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                            <li><a href="browse.php?">all</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;type=1">Laptop</a></li><li><a href="browse.php?&amp;type=2">Chromebook</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;vendor=HP">HP</a></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;vendor=Lenovo">Lenovo</a></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;vendor=Toshiba">Toshiba</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;model=3">HP Brilliance 5000</a></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;model=1">Lenovo B50-70</a></li>
                            <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;model=2">Toshiba Portege R930</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2" id="page-numbers">
                    <!-- <p class="no-bottom-pad">136 laptops</p> -->
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="active"><a href="browse.php?&amp;page=1">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;page=2">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="browse.php?&amp;page=3">3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <a href="#" id="add-laptop-btn" class="btn btn-default" onclick="laptop_modal('new')">
                        Add Laptop
                    </a>
                    <input id="add-multiple-input" class="btn btn-default less-right-pad" type="number" min="0" max="50">
                    <a href="#" id="add-multiple-btn" class="btn btn-default less-right-pad  disabled" onclick="addMultiple();">
                        Add Multiple -&gt;
                    </a>
                    <input id="earmark-multiple-input" class="btn btn-default less-right-pad" type="number" min="0" max="50">
                    <a href="#" id="earmark-multiple-btn" class="btn btn-default less-right-pad  disabled" onclick="addMultiple();">
                        Earmark Multiple -&gt;
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```